# What is causing "unbound method __init__() must be called with instance as first argument" from this Python code?

Tags: python, init

I have this class:

```
from threading import Thread 
import time

class Timer(Thread): 
    def __init__(self, interval, function, *args, **kwargs): 
        Thread.__init__() 
        self.interval = interval 
        self.function = function 
        self.args = args 
        self.kwargs = kwargs 
        self.start()

    def run(self): 
        time.sleep(self.interval) 
        return self.function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
```

and am calling it with this script:

```
    import timer 
    def hello():
        print \"hello, world
    t = timer.Timer(1.0, hello)
    t.run()
```

and get this error and I can't figure out why: `unbound method __init__() must be called with instance as first argument`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You are doing:

```
Thread.__init__()
```

Use:

```
Thread.__init__(self)
```

Or, rather, use `super()`

Comment: That'd be `super(Thread, self).__init__()` -- but super has it's own problems too :/

Comment: @THC4k: Super has no problems, multiple inheritance has problems. And if you use multiple inheritance then super is much much better than direct calls.

Comment: super is just a recipe for disaster, specially so in multiple inheritance, more specially if there is any extensions that need reloading.

Answer (score 9):

This is a frequently asked question at SO, but the answer, in brief, is that the way you call your superclass's constructor is like:

```
super(Timer,self).__init__()
```

Answer (score 3):

First, the reason you must use:

```
Thread.__init__(self)
```

instead of

```
Thread.__init__()
```

is because you are using the class name, and not an object (an instance of the class), so you cannot call a method in the same way as an object.

Second, if you are using Python 3, the recommended style for invoking a super class method from a sub class is:

```
super().method_name(parameters)
```

Although in Python 3 is possible to use:

```
SuperClassName.method_name(self, parameters)
```

It is an old style of syntax that is not the prefer style.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to pass 'self' as an argument to 'Thread.**init**'.  After that, it works on my machines.