# How to reload a module that is imported in other modules

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I have a problem in reloading modules that are imported and used in a different module. For clarity, let's consider the example where I have two modules:

First Module: operation.py

```
def f(x,y):
  return x+y
```

Second Module: test_operation.py

```
import operation
x=3
y=4
z= operation.f(x,y)
print z
```

If I go to the interpreter and write:

```
import test_operation
```

I will get 4 printed (z=4). If I change the function f in the first module operation.py to be:

```
def f(x,y):
  return x+y+1
```

and then I write in the interpreter reload(test_operation), I will still get 4 printed instead of 5. It seems then that it reloads the module test_operation.py, but it doesn't reload the module operation.py that is imported in test_operation.py.

How do I solve such problem ? and In general case how do I make sure that all imported modules in my code are re-imported (or reloaded) every time they are changed ?

Comment: use `reload(operation)`, then `reload(test_operation)`.

Comment: you are reloading the already imported module on memory after your change in operation.py not the new one with your edit

Comment: I understand that I can reload modules one by one by hand, but is there a more automatic method that reload a module and all its imported modules, and goes like this recursively ? Is there a deep reload (like there is a copy and deep copy) ?

Answer (score 0):

From the interpreter: just reload `operation` within `test_operation` module context using full path:

```
reload(test_operation.operation)
```

In `test_operation.py`, you could call `reload(operation)` so reloading `test_operation` would also reload `operation`

for full recursive reload check here (not sure it's a good idea...): [Recursive version of 'reload'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506971/recursive-version-of-reload)

Comment: Yes, indeed what you said works. I checked also the link you shared for the recursive reload, it's an adhoc built recursive function. I thought that there is a built-in method like reload, because it if there are many modules that should be reloaded, and those same modules import other modules that should be reloaded, it could be a slow procedure to  do that by hand. Why don't you think that recursive reload is not a good idea ?

Comment: reloading everything may be slow, that's all.

Comment: Yes, I understand, but is there a built-in function to do that ? Like reload ? (so it will be similar to what is provided by copy and deepcopy)