# Deep Reload Modules from only One Package

Tags: python, python-import

How do you deep reload a package without importing modules from any other outside packages?

For example, for reloading the following:

```
# example_pkg.py
import logging  # do not reload this stdlib package
import example_pkg.ex_mod  # reload this module
```

IPython's [`deepreload`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.lib.deepreload.html) module cannot specify a whitelist for imports and uses module level variables during reloads which makes it unreliable for threaded environments.

A question similar to this has been asked [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506971/recursive-version-of-reload), but it focused on discovering dependencies (as was [mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15506971/recursive-version-of-reload#comment21958372_15506971) in a comment) not exclusively within a single package.

Answer (score 2):

Using the [`sys`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html) and [`importlib`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html) modules, a function can be written to remove the package and its modules from Python's import cache. This allows for the package to reload its child modules when it is re-imported.

```
import sys
import importlib
from types import ModuleType

def deep_reload(m: ModuleType):
    name = m.__name__  # get the name that is used in sys.modules
    name_ext = name + '.'  # support finding sub modules or packages
    del m
    
    def compare(loaded: str):
        return (loaded == name) or loaded.startswith(name_ext)
    
    all_mods = tuple(sys.modules)  # prevent changing iterable while iterating over it
    sub_mods = filter(compare, all_mods)
    for pkg in sub_mods:
        del sys.modules[pkg]  # remove sub modules and packages from import cache
    
    return importlib.import_module(name)
```

This code can be extended with a [`Lock`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#threading.Lock) to make it thread-safe as well:

```
from threading import Lock

sys_mod_lock = Lock()  # all accesses to sys.modules must be programmed to acquire this lock first
# this means do not use any builtin import mechanism such as the 'import' statement once the following function is being used
# instead use importlib's import_module function while sys_mod_lock is acquired

def tsafe_reload(m: ModuleType):
    with sys_mod_lock:
        return deep_reload(m)
```

**Note:** these functions come with one of the caveats from the standard library's [`reload`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#importlib.reload). Any references elsewhere in the program leading to the old package will be maintained and will not be replaced automatically. For that, you can look at [`globalsub`](http://pythonhosted.org/globalsub/), which can replace all references to an object in the interpreter with a different object (usually for debugging purposes).

Comment: There are two typos in your code: `sub_pkgs` should be `sub_mods` and there is an extra colon that should be deleted.
But it works.

Comment: @CarlosPinzón edited. Thank you for the corrections.